# Why doesn't the Facebook Share example work?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, user-controls

Trying to implement the example from here.

> Facebook Share passes along the URL of
>   your page to our servers, which in
>   turn looks up certain HTML tags within
>   it. Those tags are used to display a
>   preview of the page. In order to
>   provide this preview, we always look
>   for the title of the page, a summary
>   of the main content and an image.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share

I added the share button to my site as described on the share page linked above.

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
```

In the header I added the tags it requires to create the preview in the news feed.
(I used the example tags, just to see if it would work.)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Smith hails 'unique' Wable legacy" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="John Smith claims beautiful football 
            is the main legacy of Akhil Wable's decade at the club. " /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" />


</script>
```

When the shared button is clicked it takes me to small shared window and I hit share.

However, when I navigate to my news feed, no preview of the page shows and none of the header tag information. It just shows:

Greg McNulty http://localhost:2259/iState/Shared.aspx?id=a051fc1b-4f51-485b-a07d-0f378528974e localhost 7 minutes ago · LikeUnlike · Comment · Share

Why isn't the preview working? (I get this same result without the header tags.)

Thank You.

(FYI - I am using the share because it allows for multiple shares of the same page whenever needed, compared to the like that allows it once and then the button physically changes saying the page is already liked.)

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like suggests a code and informs about errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test how Facebook servers see your webpage by feeding the URL to this service.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

In order for OpenGraph to work a facebook server must be able to visit the URL without a session or cookie.  This means "localhost" web pages cannot pass open graph data.